# Gnome keyring issue

Tags: gnome, opensuse, gpg, gnome-keyring

I am attempting to restore some files to an OpenSUSE 12.3 machine that was backed up with deja-dup (duplicity). When prompted for the password to decrypt the backup, I enter the correct password and I am prompted repeatedly with no progress.

The error given in `/var/log/messages` is:

```
The gnome keyring socket is not owned with the same credentials as the 
    user login: <username removed>
gkr-pam: couldn't unlock the login keyring
```

In deja-dup's debugging log I have:

```
DUPLICITY: ERROR 31 GPGError
DUPLICITY: . GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:
DUPLICITY: . ===== Begin GnuPG log =====
DUPLICITY: . gpg: WARNING: "--no-use-agent" is an obsolete option - it has no effect
DUPLICITY: . gpg: CAST5 encrypted data
DUPLICITY: . gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
DUPLICITY: . gpg: decryption failed: Bad session key
DUPLICITY: . gpg: block_filter 0x7f969a828e60: read error (size=15648,a->size=15648)
DUPLICITY: . gpg: block_filter: pending bytes!
DUPLICITY: . ===== End GnuPG log =====
```

Comment: can you use `duplicity` directly or try to decrypt the files yourself via `gpg`?

Comment: no. duplicity won't work. It appears to be a gpg issue. Question updated.

Comment: how about https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1242074#p1242074 i.e. unset `GPG_AGENT_INFO`

Comment: nope. no luck. I logged a bug with dejadup team. It could be configuration, but they may still be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install python-oauth to fix this problem.